# ¿Cómo hago para que el bean escuche el valor de un input dentro de un overlay en Primefaces?

Tags: java, html, primefaces

Tengo un problema en cuanto a un `<p:inputText>` que está dentro de un `<p:overlayPanel>` lo que pasa es que ese `input` inserta su valor en una propiedad del bean, pero cuando hago que llame el método que necesita esa propiedad, llega vacía, no sé cual sea el error pero me empezó a molestar desde que puse el `input` dentro del `overlay`

Adjunto el código

```
 <p:overlayPanel id="displayPanel" for="btnCorreoDisplay" hideEffect="fade" dynamic="true" style="width:400px" dismissable="false" showCloseIcon="true" appendToBody="false">
    <p:panelGrid columns="1" styleClass="ui-panelgrid-blank" style="margin: 0 auto;text-align: center;" id="panelCorreoElect">

      <p:remoteCommand name="myRemCo"
                 action="#{CitaController.llenarCorreos()}" process="@this txtCorreoInscrito"
                 update="txtCorreoInscrito selCorreosMasivo"/>

      <p:inputText  
        label="#{labels['CitasDocente.correo']}" size="15"
        maxlength="40" style="width: 200px"
        onkeypress="if (event.keyCode == 13) { myRemCo(); return false;}"
        value="#{CitaController.objInscripcionCitaSelected.correoElectronico}"
        placeholder="Ingresa el correo electronico"
        required="false" id="txtCorreoInscrito"/>   
            <h:outputText value="Presiona enter para adicionar" style="font-size: smaller" id="otxCorreosDisplay" />  
  </p:panelGrid>
</p:overlayPanel>
```

Cabe resaltar que todo esto está dentro de un `dialog` pero como este tiene más contenido no lo pongo dentro, además de que está también dentro de un `form`. Se los agradecería si pudieran ayudarme.

Comment: suponiendo que tu bean esta correcto, revisaste las librerias de tu Bean? Envia el codigo de tu Bean.

Comment: Ya, ya vi que era, al parecer ese `overlayPanel` se viene creando debajo de toda la vista por lo tanto si está dentro de un `form` éste no toma en cuenta el `overlay` ya que se estaría creando por fuera

Answer (score 0):

El `overlayPanel` se crea después de toda la vista, por lo tanto sí se pone dentro de un `form` éste no lo toma en cuenta, ya que el `overlayPanel` se crea después de toda la vista, la solución es simplemente poner un `form` dentro del `overlayPanel` y ya con esto sí envía la información de los campos que están dentro de él.

```
<p:overlayPanel id="displayPanel" for="btnCorreoDisplay" hideEffect="fade" dynamic="true" style="width:400px" dismissable="false" showCloseIcon="true" appendToBody="false">
  <h:form>
    <p:panelGrid columns="1" styleClass="ui-panelgrid-blank" style="margin: 0 auto;text-align: center;" id="panelCorreoElect">

      <p:remoteCommand name="myRemCo"
                 action="#{CitaController.llenarCorreos()}" process="@this txtCorreoInscrito"
                 update="txtCorreoInscrito selCorreosMasivo"/>

      <p:inputText  
        label="#{labels['CitasDocente.correo']}" size="15"
        maxlength="40" style="width: 200px"
        onkeypress="if (event.keyCode == 13) { myRemCo(); return false;}"
        value="#{CitaController.objInscripcionCitaSelected.correoElectronico}"
        placeholder="Ingresa el correo electronico"
        required="false" id="txtCorreoInscrito"/>   
            <h:outputText value="Presiona enter para adicionar" style="font-size: smaller" id="otxCorreosDisplay" />  
    </p:panelGrid>
  </h:form>
</p:overlayPanel>
```